# inviting friends to your server minecraft java

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know that if you create a single player and then change it into a server you can invite your friends to play together, but i wanted to know if i can change the settings so that only my friends who i invited are allowed to join. Just incase someone ramdomly found my server and went inside to destroy everything, if you know the answer, please reply, thank you :3

Comment: can you not just add a password to the server?

Comment: I haven't done this in a long time, but I believe there's a whitelist option to allow only certain users to join the server.

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/whitelist

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Please convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3):

First, use `whitelist on` to enable the whitelist, which will only allow specified players to join.

You can add players to the whitelist using `whitelist add <targets>`

`<targets>` is defined as:

> Must be a collection of game profiles (player profiles), which can be a player name (must be a real one if the server is in online mode), or a player-type target selector.
> Specifies the player profile(s) to be added to or removed from the whitelist.

From [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/whitelist)